# A C# list of custom childs similar with android ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, custom-controls

I need to create a list in c# with click-able and customizable child elements.

Check attached image (red square) to get a feeling of what I would like to end up with. I tested on a control called `"list view"`. I can add an icon and a label, it is not enough, I need more customization.

So question: Which c# control should I use? Maybe share a link if you know something useful.

**Note**: I don't really know or enjoy C# (I am Java guy), as IDE I use `Visual Studio C#`, express edition and I would love to minimize the coding part as much as possible

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, create a user control (says ContactRow.cs)
2. Draw what ever UI that you need on it. (Image, text, etc)
3. Secondly, Create a container form (says ContactList.cs)
4. Add a TableLayoutPanel (Or FlowLayoutPanel Or equivalent) into container form.
5. Set AutoScroll property = true so that it scrolls.
6. In run time, you can new an instance of your ContactRow.cs and set all the values.
7. Then add it into the TableLayoutPanel using the TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(contactrow)

Comment: used table layout panel and works.. need to tweak it to look better.. but this doesn't seem to have a fill to form property or something similar.. ?? how do I go about that? (fill form)

Comment: Did you tried .Dock = DockStyle.Fill ? It is available for table layout and user control.